# Angular 11 : Fetch all Pages in parallel

Tags: angular, parallel-processing

There is a external API which returns all items as below :

```
{
 page : 1,
 per_page : 10,
 total : 200,
 items : [],
}
```

I want to fetch all pages. For example : In above scenario Total Pages = 20 (Total/per_page i.e 200/10)

What is the best way to make 1st call and know number of pages and then make rest all calls parallelly and merge it?

Using Angular 11 - concatMap, flatMap, forkJoin etc.

**Solution**:

Based on @Michael comment's updated code as shown below :

```
getAllItems(): void {
    this.itemService.getItemsByPage(1).pipe(
        switchMap((itemPage: ItemPage) => {
          const totalPages = Math.ceil(itemPage.total/itemPage.per_page);
          const req$ = Array(totalPages).fill(1).map((_, index) =>
            this.itemService.getItemsByPage(index + 1)
          );
          return forkJoin(req$);
        })
      ).subscribe(
        res => {
          for (let page = 1; page <= res.length; page++) {
            //Collect all responses using res[page] 
          }
        },
        error => { 
          console.log("Error Fetching Items");
        }
      );
  }
```

Comment: do you know the url/resource to of that 20 pages that you wanna fetch? what is the pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown how to structure the request to input the total pages 20 in the HTTP request. So I'll use pseudo URLs.

1. Trigger the first request.
2. Use `switchMap` to switch to the other request i.e. fetching 20 pages. Angular HTTP requests complete after single emission. So no difference here b/n `switchMap`, `mergeMap`, `concatMap` or `exhaustMap`.
3. Two possibilities:

   3.1. If each page is an individual request, then use `forkJoin` to fetch them all in parallel.

   3.2. If all pages are fetched in a single request, then return it directly.

**3.1: `forkJoin`**

```js
this.http.get('first request').pipe(
  switchMap((res: any) => {
    const totalPages = res['total'] / res['per_page'];
    // Convert the number 20 to 20 HTTP reqs. Again, not enough info is provided.
    const req$ = Array(totalPages).fill(1).map((_, index) =>
      this.http.get('page index+1')
    );
    return forkJoin(req$);
  })
).subscribe(
  res => {
    // res: ['res for page 1', 'res for page 2', ..., 'res for page 20'];
  },
  error => { }
);
```

**3.2: single request**

```js
this.http.get('first request').pipe(
  switchMap((res: any) => 
    this.http.get('url for 20 pages')
  )
).subscribe(
  res => {
    // res: depends on the backend;
  },
  error => { }
);
```

Comment: Getting error on "Array.fill". Also, added code snippet as shown above.
API is paginated.

Comment: It should've been `Array(totalPages).fill(1)`, sorry. Please try again. The `1` could be any value, it doesn't matter since we've be mapping to HTTP request using `map` function's `index` parameter.

Comment: Do we require to mention take(1) OR need to explicitly close observable?

Comment: Angular HTTP observables are `take(1)` by default. The `forkJoin` is externally a single observable with a single emission. So it isn't required.

Comment: Thanks!! Working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the API to retrieve all available pages and total of items, and then implement some logic to use forkJoin to call the API in parallel for the number of pages that you have